# OpenLayers 6 setTileLoadFunction() documented example uses URL.createObjectURL(data), need to call revokeObjectURL() to avoid a memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, openlayers-6

The OpenLayers latest documentation here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html
shows an example of how to use the setTileLoadFunction().  Here is the example as provided:

```
import TileState from 'ol/TileState';

source.setTileLoadFunction(function(tile, src) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.addEventListener('loadend', function (evt) {
    var data = this.response;
    if (data !== undefined) {
      tile.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    } else {
      tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
    }
  });
  xhr.addEventListener('error', function () {
    tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
  });
  xhr.open('GET', src);
  xhr.send();
});
```

URL.createObjectURL() creates a permanent object that must be revoked manually.  This code example will leak memory. As the tiles get discarded, the URL objects we created stick around.

See my answer for the correct example code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two changes I'm making in this example.  One of for compatibility with older browsers, like IE, where you cannot set the responseType immediately, you have to wait for onloadstart as follows:

```
xhr.onloadstart = function (ev) {
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
}
```

and you need to release the URL object created once the tile is loaded:

```
    tile.getImage().onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
```

So here is the full example as it should be written.

```
import TileState from 'ol/TileState';

source.setTileLoadFunction(function(tile, src) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onloadstart = function() {
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  }
  xhr.addEventListener('loadend', function (evt) {
    var data = this.response;
    if (data !== undefined) {
      tile.getImage().src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
      tile.getImage().onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
    } else {
      tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
    }
  });
  xhr.addEventListener('error', function () {
    tile.setState(TileState.ERROR);
  });
  xhr.open('GET', src);
  xhr.send();
});
```

Comment: Note in some browsers (including ios 11.2 on iPad) the createObjectURL fails because the data object passed in is not of the proper type.  Additional error checking may be in order if you think the page may be accessed with older devices.  If/when I get enough additional info, I will edit this answer with additional error checking requirements.